# How to associate models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a ROR app with Users and Groups and I want to be able to link them with an associative model called Memberships.

My problem is that when I try to create a group with one member, the `members` array for the new group is always empty.

I tried creating a group like this:

```
def create (user)
  @group = Group.new(create_group_params)
  user.join(@group)
  user.save
  @group.save
end
```

but `@group.members` is empty when I print it out. How can I make the user a member of the group?

Here are my models:

Group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :passive_memberships, class_name: "Membership",
                                foreign_key: "club_id",
                                  dependent: :destroy

  has_many :members, through: :passive_memberships, source: :member
end
```

User.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_memberships, class_name:  "Membership",
                                foreign_key: "member_id",
                                dependent:   :destroy

  has_many :memberships, through: :active_memberships, source: :club

  def join(group)
    active_memberships.create(club_id: group.id)
  end
end
```

Membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :club, class_name: "Group"
  validates :member_id, presence: true
  validates :club_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I have to save the group before the user can join it.

```
def create (user)
  @group = Group.new(create_group_params)
  @group.save
  user.join(@group)
  user.save
end
```